# How to read a specific name from the list of files in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have several files that starts with the name as VCALogParser_output_ARW.log, VCALogParser_output_ARW_PREVIOUS.log, VCALogParser_output_GED.log, VCALogParser_output_GED_PREVIOUS.log and so on. I just want to read the file that starts with VCALogParser_output_ARW.log but not the PREVIOUS.log files. ARW, GED and so on the languages (example : ARW is arabic, GED is german and so on). I tried the below code but it is read both the VCALogParser_output_.log and VCALogParser_output_ARW_PREVIOUS.log file also. Can someone please tell me what is the mistake with the following below code ?

```
with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_output:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory): 
        for filename in filenames:
           if re.match('VCALogParser_output_[A-Z]+\.log', filename): 
             #if (filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output') and (not filename.endswith('previous.log'))):
                str=filename
                str=str.replace("VCALogParser_output_", "")
                str=str.replace(".log", "")
```

Comment: Does the `filename` include *only* the file name, or the whole path? Also, you'd better put an `r` before the regex pattern string.

Comment: Works for me. Can you show output, that shows your behavior?

Comment: I tried that but it is reading the current and previous log file also.

Comment: Were is the code, that actually reads the files?

Comment: Can't you simply do: `if filename.startswith('VCALogParser_output_') and not filename.endswith('_PREVIOUS.log'):`?

Comment: Do you want to use a regex? Otherwise this would be more simple to use `startswith()` and `not ... .endswith()` to choose what names you keep.

Comment: Try `if re.search(r'[/\\]VCALogParser_output_[A-Z]+\.log$', filename): `

Comment: I found the problem : my code is correct. but how to read just only a  specific directory. It also reads the other directory within it. how to read a specific directory ?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to list one directory, use `glob`:

```
with open(output_filename, 'w') as f_output:
    for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(directory, 'VCALogParser_output_???.log')):
        # do whatever you want with filename
```